# how to get WCF to bypass ISP proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, proxy

Suppose I have a WCF service which I need to host on a server in a country which blocks access to many sites.

So if I host my WCF for testing purpose on a server that is not in such a country, it works perfectly — but whenever I try to deploy it to any server in this country I can’t access it.

Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

No?

If the ISP uses a transparent procy, you can not easily bypass it.

There are methods - mostly involving using a VPN to go to a proxy outside the country - but they are not WCF level.

Comment: can you plz explain more about the methods to fix this ?

Comment: Ask your sys admin. That simple. Use proxies external to the country, if that does not work, OPEN A VPN OUT OF THE COUNTRY. There are various providers allowing that - and then route all WWCF trafic through that VPN.

Comment: but how can i configure the webservice on serverside to use a proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

i got it working now, transparent proxies used to censorship would never block wcf , it was a silly problem in my windows server 2008 which is : Start > administrative tools > server manager > features > add feature > .netframwork 3.5 > activate WCF!!!